# jQuery works fine in chrome fails in IE9/IE8 etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the following jquery (theres a lot of it, sorry) to load in a dynamic dropdown and to update when one of them changes. In IE it loads the dropdowns at the start, but doesn't seem to fire on the onchange events (even in IE9)

Any help will really be appreciated

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        <%= loadValues%>
        $('.dropone').change(function() {
            var tmpRoomID = $('.drpChg1').val();
            $(".drpChg2").empty();
            $(".drpChg2").load("ajaxdropdown.aspx?drpType=room&roomid=" + tmpRoomID, function() {
                updateTB()
            });
        });

        $('.droptwo').change(function() {
            updateTB()
        });

        $('.dropfive').change(function() {
            updateTB()
        });

        $('.dropfour').change(function() {
            updateTB()
        });

        $('.dropthree').change(function() {
            var tmpRoomID = $('.drpChg3').val();
            $(".drpChg4").empty();
            $(".drpChg4").load("ajaxdropdown.aspx?drpType=cat&catID=" + tmpRoomID, function() {
                updateTB()
            });
            $(".drpChg5").load("ajaxdropdown.aspx?drpType=subcat&subcatID=" + tmpRoomID, function() {
                updateTB()
            });

        });

        function updateTB() {
            $('#drop1').val($(".drpChg1").val());
            $('#drop2').val($(".drpChg2").val());
            $('#drop3').val($(".drpChg3").val());
            $('#drop4').val($(".drpChg4").val());
            $('#drop5').val($(".drpChg5").val());
        }

        function loadValues() {
            var roomID = "0"
            $('.dropone').load('ajaxdropdown.aspx', function() {
                $('#drop1').val($(".drpChg1").val());
            });
            $('.droptwo').load('ajaxdropdown.aspx?drpType=room&roomid=' + roomID + '', function() {
                $('#drop2').val($(".drpChg2").val());
            });

            $('.dropthree').load('ajaxdropdown.aspx?drpType=type' + '', function() {
                $('#drop3').val($(".drpChg3").val());
            });

            $('.dropfour').load('ajaxdropdown.aspx?drpType=cat&catID=' + roomID + '', function() {
                $('#drop4').val($(".drpChg4").val());
            });

            $('.dropfive').load('ajaxdropdown.aspx?drpType=subcat&subcatID=' + roomID + '', function() {
                $('#drop5').val($(".drpChg5").val());
            });

        }

            function loadNewValues() {
            var roomID = "0"
            $('.dropone').load('ajaxdropdown.aspx', function() {
                $('.drpChg1').val($("#drop1").val());   
            });

            $('.droptwo').load('ajaxdropdown.aspx?drpType=room&roomid=' + roomID + '', function() {
                $('.drpChg2').val($("#drop2").val());  
            });

            $('.dropthree').load('ajaxdropdown.aspx?drpType=type' + '', function() {
                $('.drpChg3').val($("#drop3").val());  
            });

            $('.dropfour').load('ajaxdropdown.aspx?drpType=cat&catID=' + roomID + '', function() {
                $('.drpChg4').val($("#drop4").val());  
            });

            $('.dropfive').load('ajaxdropdown.aspx?drpType=subcat&subcatID=' + roomID + '', function() {
               $('.drpChg5').val($("#drop5").val());  
            }); 
       }


    });
</script>
```

Comment: Any errors in IE console? Anyway there is A LOT of code smell in your script, consider grouping stuff by classes, caching jQuery selectors, and reusing functions.

Comment: I assume you're using some server side language (.Net?). What does `<%= loadValues%>` evaluate to?

Answer (score 0):

Try out those links you refer to as normal links.
Sometimes there's a confusion between browsers needing a link to:

- Somefile.asp?blah=yaddah
- /Somefile.asp?blah=yaddah
- ./Somefile.asp?blah=yaddah

I see this with CSS sometimes.